# How do I manipulate a RichTextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Say, I have two RichTextBox. I will paste a code snippet on at first one with format, indentation and Syntax highlight.

I want to add only code tag before starting point and last end of the text. When I will hit okay button, it will show it in the next RichTextBox with the tag and everything of the code snippet will be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start out with this:

```
rtext2.Text = "<code>" + rtext1.Text + "</code>";
```

Does that give you an idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: But it doesn't keep the syntax color .

Answer (score 1):

I think this code might work for you if you are using Windows Forms application

```
    //Give the RichTextBox some text.
    string sometext = "www.asp.net.";
    rchSource.Text = sometext;
    rchSource.Select(sometext.IndexOf("www"), "www".Length);
    rchSource.SelectionFont = new Font(rchSource.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic);

    rchSource.Select(sometext.IndexOf("."), ".".Length);
    rchSource.SelectionFont = new Font(rchSource.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    rchSource.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;

    rchSource.Select(sometext.IndexOf("asp"), "asp".Length);
    rchSource.SelectionFont = new Font(rchSource.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    rchSource.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    rchSource.Select(sometext.IndexOf("net"), "net".Length);
    rchSource.SelectionFont = new Font(rchSource.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);

    rchSource.Select(0, 0);
```

Reference link: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/SetRichTextBoxFontandColor.htm)